# Error when trying to migrate django application with south

Tags: python, database, django, migration

I am getting this error when running "./manage.py migrate app_name"

```
While loading migration 'whatever.0001_initial':
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 14, in <module> execute_manager(settings)

...tons of other stuff..

   raise KeyError("The model '%s' from the app '%s' is not available in this migration." % (model, app))
KeyError: "The model 'appuser' from the app 'whatever' is not available in this migration."
```

I am sure that model "appuser" is both in application models.py and in 0001_initial.py

AppUser model from models.py:

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField('Person')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('is_one', 'one'),
            ('is_two', 'two')
        )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.person.__unicode__()
```

AppUser model from 0001_initial.py:

```
    # Adding model 'AppUser'
    db.create_table('app_appuser', (
        ('person', models.OneToOneField(orm.Person)),
        ('id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True)),
        ('user', models.ForeignKey(orm['auth.User'], unique=True)),
    ))
    db.send_create_signal('app', ['AppUser'])
    ...
    'app.appuser': {
        'Meta': {'permissions': "(('is_one','one'),('is_two','two'))"},
        'id': ('models.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
        'person': ('models.OneToOneField', ["'Person'"], {}),
        'user': ('models.ForeignKey', ['User'], {'unique': 'True'})
    },
```

I am trying to run it on empty database (ie. no "app_*" tables) like that:

```
manage.py migrate app
```

This seem to be happening only on python 2.5 on Mac OS, no probs with Ubuntu/python 2.6

Question - how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with the order of models in the 0001_initial.py file. There was a class which derived from AppUser. When I re-created the migration on Mac OS with

```
manage.py startmigration app --initial
```

and compared that to one generated on Ubuntu the order of models was different. So when I changed the order to match the one on Mac OS, everything worked fine.

This problem seems to exist only in 0.5 version of south and is supposedly fixed on trunk.