# south migration error app "is not available in this migration"

Tags: django, migration

This problem is basically the same as the previous question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880989/error-when-trying-to-migrate-django-application-with-south).

However, the answer there does not work for me. I've installed the trunk version of south, manually entered the import line in the migration file in question, and done a full 'startmigration' in a separate directory and examined the 0001_initial.py file.

I have a Django project with several applications in it, one of them (named 'core') being referred to by the others. The south migration is trying to create a new table, with a column that has a foreign key to a model in core.

I'm currently importing core in the migration in question (0006), and I even added it to migration 0001, although it doesn't seem like that should matter.

Before I do something drastic, like removing that field, running the migration, and adding the field manually, is there a known manual workaround for fixing this south issue?

Comment: Well, I ended up doing it manually. I've recently had to add a new model, and I'm getting the same issue. So, any solutions?

Or do I switch to Django Evolution, or just give up and use SQL?

Answer (score 11):

You probably did not use the [`--freeze`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ormfreezing.html) option like this:

```
python manage.py startmigration <appname> migrate_core --freeze core
```

Answer (score 2):

Having created a migration like so:

./manage.py startmygration appname --model NewModel

This error occurs:
"The model 'program' from the app 'core' is not available in this migration."

Recreating the migration like this fixes it:

./managepy startmigration appname --model NewModel --freeze core.Program

Just doing "--freeze core" did not do the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive this error by trying to access a class that resides in another django app.  Check to make sure the class you are trying to access is in the `models` dictionary.